# syncing elasticsearch indices with postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, elasticsearch, event-sourcing

I have an event table in PostgreSQL which is made based on the event-sourcing pattern, as you can see it here: [image]

I want to export these data into their appropriate elasticsearch indices whenever a new row is created in the event table. I wonder what is the best approach as I'm using spring boot Rest API for my application.

Comment: Using logstash might be a good approach. Have a look at [logstash jdbc plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc). Also read this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin).

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant thank you for your answer but, could you pls elaborate on how to convert the JSON strings in the payload field in order to import them in the appropriate index?

Comment: You can make use of [logstash filter plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) and for parsing json you can use [json filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#_description_135).

Comment: If you have an event-sourced system, you most certainly need CQRS, so how do your projections work? Of this is the first projection? The simplest way to implement a real-time subscription on any RDBMS is continuous polling with DELETE that returns the result.